# Como mudar o formato do DataTime em C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, firebird

Eu recebo uma string com a data, coloco essa string em um `DateTime`, e coloco esse `DateTime` em uma variável do banco.

O problema é que a variável do banco usa um formato diferente de `DateTime` (**MMddyyyy**), e o `DateTime` do C# usa o formato (**ddMMyyyy**).

Preciso mudar isto via código, e não sei como.

**Uso o banco de dados Firebird, drive ODBC. Visual Studio 2013.**

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer a conversão:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```